# Expresso Store 1.6.5 with UPS Shipping: The maximum per package weight

Tags: expresso-store, ups-shipping

I'm sure this has been covered and I've seen the updates in 2.0 that have fixed this issue but, is there a work around for Version: 1.6.5 pertaining to "The maximum per package weight for the selected service from the selected country is 150.00 pounds." error.  I want to break these up into multiple packages.

I'm assuming its in here:

```
<Package>
                    <PackagingType>
                        <Code>'.$this->settings['packaging'].'</Code>
                    </PackagingType>
                    <Dimensions>
                        <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>'.$dimension_units.'</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
                        <Length>'.sprintf("%.1f", $order_length).'</Length>
                        <Height>'.sprintf("%.1f", $order_height).'</Height>
                        <Width>'.sprintf("%.1f", $order_width).'</Width>
                    </Dimensions>
                    <PackageWeight>
                        <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>'.$weight_units.'</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
                        <Weight>'.sprintf("%.1f", $order_weight).'</Weight>
                    </PackageWeight>
                    '.$insure_order.'
                </Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature (automatically splitting packages into multiple orders) was first added in Store 1.6.1, as can be seen in the [release notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_1_6_1):

> Updated the UPS shipping plugin to split large orders into multiple packages

The code you have pasted above seems to be from Store 1.6.0 or earlier.

Therefore, if you are using 1.6.5 as you mentioned, you should not be seeing this problem (or even that code). I suggest you delete your entire third_party/store folder on the server and re-upload a clean version of 1.6.5 to ensure you are actually running the latest version.